# WPF Two-Way Binding with custom gets and sets

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, getter-setter

I have a property:

```
private int myProperty;

public int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
       return myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        // do something special
    }
}
```

I want to bind this property to a textbox like so:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay} />
```

Such that when the user changes the value in the textbox, the set is invoked. But the binding doesn't seem to work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're expecting it to update immediately, you'll need `UpdateSourceTrigger`. I'm not sure whether that's what you're asking, though. This should still work when the textbox loses focus.

Comment: Did you set the DataContext?

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox Text={Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />
```

You don't need to specify Mode=TwoWay as TwoWay is the default binding mode for TextBox controls.  PropertyChanged as UpdateSourceTrigger will execute the setter on every keypress that modifies the text.  You can also use the LostFocus UpdateSourceTrigger if you want to delay the setter until the user has finished inputting the value and tabs or clicks to the next control.